Not showing images outside src folder when deploy spring boot app on railway.app
So here in my SpringBoot application project I have a folder name "food-photos" outside the src folder that I used for containing my website's dishes' photos, all photos show normally on localhost. However it seems to be missing the folder "food-photos" and not show images when I deploy my project on railway, how do I fix this problem?
This is my github project: https://github.com/quyen542/thesis_new
I have searched for all information on how to fix it on Google but still cannot find a way or instructions to fix it.
Thanks,

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
